# Which tools to create source and binary drops of Visual Studio solutions & projects

Tags: visual-studio

### BACKGROUND

What I'd like to be able to do is create "packages" (simple ZIP files) of my Visual Studio solutions and projects.

For example I want to be able to do the following:

- Create a "source" package of an entire solution (stripped of any source control settings or built binaries)
- Do the same as above except for a specific project or specific subset of projects in the solution
- Create "binary" packages of an entire solution - no source code, just what is in the "bin" - older - where I could specifically get just "Release" or "Debug" binaries
- Do the same as above except for a specific project or specific subset of projects in the solution

Despite googling and looking on the Visual Studio Gallery I haven't found anything that can do this.

### QUESTION

Can someone identify any tools or techniques that can help? I've previously done something like this for VS2005 in Python and can certainly do it again, but if there is a pre-built solution I would love to hear about it.

### NOTES

- I'm using both VS2010 and VS2008
- Ideally a solution (for me) would involve right clicking on the solution node or the project node and getting a context menu, but command-line tools are OK also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reading this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx

and came across these two links that I thought might be of use here:

1. http://code.google.com/p/treetrim/ (I like this the best)
2. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/clean-sources-plus.html

Perhaps they could be used in conjunction with a menu extension for the solution explorer.

Hope that helps :)